# RSpec Test Using Matchers is Failing with a Non-descriptive Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

**My problem with an RSpec test:** I'm following [Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#code-have_error_message). We define an RSpec matcher `have_error_message` that is working for me. I am trying to define a matcher to test the inverse called `not_have_error_message`, which I invoke

`it { should not_have_error_message }`.

I am doing this because I tried `it { should_not have_error_message }` and got the error

```
Capybara::ExpectationNotMet: expected to find css "div.alert.alert-error" with text "Invalid" but there were no matches
```

**I would like to know** 1) if it is possible to accomplish this using should_not and have_error_message and 2) what I am doing wrong that is causing not_have_error_message to fail. Thanks!

Here's the code:

spec/features/authentication_pages_spec.rb (irrelevant part omitted)

```
describe "Authentication" do
  
  subject { page }

  describe "signin" do

    ...

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_content('Sign in') }
      it { should have_title('Sign in') }
      it { should have_error_message('Invalid') } 

      describe "after visiting another page" do
         before { click_link "Home" }
         it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
         it { should not_have_error_message }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

spec/support/utilities.rb

```
include ApplicationHelper

def valid_signin(user)
   fill_in "Email",     with: user.email
   fill_in "Password",  with: user.password
   click_button "Sign in"
end

RSpec::Matchers.define :have_error_message do |message|
   match do |page|
      expect(page).to have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: message)
   end
end

RSpec::Matchers.define :not_have_error_message do
   match do |page|
      expect(page).not_to have_selector('div.alert.alert-error')
   end
end
```

And I'm getting the error:

```
  1) Authentication signin with invalid information after visiting another page 
     Failure/Error: it { should not_have_error_message }
       expected #<Capybara::Session> to not have error message
     # ./spec/features/authentication_pages_spec.rb:44:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

You can see I also run the equivalent test:

`it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }`

directly above the failing test and it passes.

Comment: Do you have `require 'spec_helper'` in your `spec/features/authentication_pages_spec.rb`?

Comment: I've been staring at this for quite a while. Your `should_not have_error_message` should have worked, as should have your `should not_have_error_message`.

Comment: yup I have require 'spec_helper'

Comment: Thanks for the comment Peter, given that `should have_error_message` is working I can't think of where I'm going wrong since the should_not implementation should work. Let me know if I can provide any other details that would help get to the bottom of this. I'm using capybara 2.1.0 and rspec 2.13.1

Answer (score 1):

When defining the RSpec matchers, the block is meant to return true or false (see [this wiki](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/Custom-Matchers)).

The way you have defined your matchers, you are actually making the assertion within an assertion. When the inner expectation fails, this raises an exception that causes the outer expectation to give unexpected results.

So that the custom matchers evaluate to true/false, use the `has_selector?` and `has_not_selector?` methods. Your custom matchers should be:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_error_message do |message|
   match do |page|
      page.has_selector?('div.alert.alert-error', text: message)
   end
end

RSpec::Matchers.define :not_have_error_message do
   match do |page|
      page.has_no_selector?('div.alert.alert-error')
   end
end
```